# Node - Import class from module in another package

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I'm writing an app using Node.js. Specifically, I'm using Node v10.3.0. This app is located in a directory located at `./my-module-console/index.js`. This app have a package.json file located at `./my-module-console/package.json`. This app references a class defined in `./my-module/items/`. It should be noted that `my-module` represents its own package. That package is defined in `./my-module/package.json`. The code in index.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

import { Item } from '../my-module/items/item.js';

async function entry() {
  let item = await Item.FindById(1);
  console.log(item);
}

entry();
```

When I attempt to run this, I get the following error:

```
import { Item } from '../my-module/items/item.js';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

What is wrong with my import statement? It looks correct to me. Am I misunderstanding something?

**item.js**

```
class Item {
    constructor() {}

    async static FindById(id) {
      console.log('finding item by id: ' + id);
    }
};

module.exports = Item;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the contents of the `item.js` file.

Comment: Please share the contents of `item.js` or share details of the file.

Comment: While import is indeed part of ES6, it is unfortunately not yet supported in NodeJS by default, and has only very recently landed support in browsers.

Comment: I just added the contents for `item.js`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @jsur ES Modules are still experimental. But if you want to use them you have to add `--experimental-modules`. If you still want to use ES Modules then you have to **rename .js to .mjs** and also the item.js, it is commonJS style now, has to be changed to ES Modules + small other fix. And also you don't really have to use 'use strict', it is strict by default. So finally it should look like this:

**index.mjs**

```
import { Item } from '../my-module/items/item';

async function entry() {
  let item = await Item.FindById(1);
  console.log(item);
}

entry();
```

**item.mjs**

```
export class Item {
    constructor() {}

    static async FindById(id) {
      console.log('finding item by id: ' + id);
    }
}
```

So now just do `node --experimental-modules index.mjs` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
class Item {
    constructor() {}

    async static FindById(id) {
      console.log('finding item by id: ' + id);
    }
};

module.exports.Item = Item; // change this line
```

---

Seccond:

```
'use strict';

// import { Item } from '../my-module/items/item.js'; // not sure if it work, it work in react, but in regular node.js can be wrong (look doc ES6)
const Item = require('../my-module/items/item.js');
var someitem = new Item();
async function entry() {
  let item = await someitem.FindById(1);
  console.log(item);
}
entry();
```

Answer (score 0):

`import { Item } from '../my-module/items/item.js';` is the ES6 syntax for importing exports from Javascript modules. Node does not support this currently without additional flags, so you'll have to use `require` instead:

`const item = require('../my-module/items/item');`

This way you'll be requiring the class `Item` being exported in `item.js`.

Also take note that you have to create an instance of the class you're exporting to use its functions in `index.js`.

Comment: That's not true though. The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interop_with_existing_modules) show that ES6 syntax for importing is allowed.

Comment: Yes, but you need the flag - that's why I said "without additional flags". Imho the best way would be to use the currently supported `require()`.

Comment: commonjs all the way

Answer (score 0):

import is experimental currently. 
As per docs

> The --experimental-modules flag can be used to enable features for
>   loading ESM modules.
>
> Once this has been set, files ending with .mjs will be able to be
>   loaded as ES Modules.
>
> node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Answer (score 0):

`Import` is not yet supported unless you use **babel compiler** to compile your ES6 code and then run it.

Using **experimental-modules** is for experiments i.e development environment. And renaming to .mjs isn't a good idea as eventually it's gonna change.

If you want to use babel js: **Write code in ES6 and compile and run it.**

[Getting started with Babel](https://medium.com/@tmtushar28/getting-started-with-webpack-aae37062c01)

Optionally,

Here's how you can quickly solve problem and move ahead:

```
const item = require('../my-module/items/item');
```

- Read more about Babel [here](https://babeljs.io/).
- About Import [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta).